# How to use log4j's FileAppenders asynchronously?

Tags: java, log4j

I work on a low-latency trading application. We'd like to increase the amount of lof4j logging that we write to file, whilst minimising the impact on our end-to-end processing time.

What is the recommended way of doing this? I think FileAppender.append is synchronous, so we need to do something a bit smarter than that....

Comment: "you think"? Have you verified that it's actually a bottleneck? That should be easy enough to do.

Comment: Hint: check [the JavaDoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html#getBufferedIO()) for the `BufferedIO` option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the appenders are synchronous. You want something like this:

http://www.spartanjava.com/2009/asynchronous-logging-with-log4j/

Comment: This link is dead.

Answer (score 4):

bear in mind that `AsyncAppender` adds a thread per appender & that increasing the amount of logging you do may mean a substantial increase in the amount of string concatentation going on which often means a substantial amount of string processing/munging/formatting which can be pretty expensive (relative to the latency involved in a low latency trading app anyway).

Answer (score 3):

If you need to log from a multithreaded application [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) and its implementation [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) are much better choice.

Comment: is it the "prudent" flag that lets you say so ?